# Small screen design goes to two rows

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to responsive design and I am trying to use bootstrap.

My problem is that I cannot get a portion of the html to display on a single row when on small screens.

I have the following HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta content="IE=11.0000" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-width=1.0">
    <link href="files/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="files/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        body, html
        {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .container-fluid
        {
            display: table !important;
            height: 100% !important;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .row-fluid
        {
            display: table-row !important;
            height: 100% !important;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .fullwidth
        {
            width: 100% !important;
        }

        @media screen and (min-width: 750px)
        {

            .top-bar-items
            {
                display: table !important;
                height: 80px;
            }
        }


        .content
        {
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .navbar-cell
        {
            padding-top: 18px;
        }

        .blue
        {
            background-color: Blue;
        }
        .red
        {
            background-color: red;
        }
        .green
        {
            background-color: green;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header> 
     <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-7 text-left">
                <a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" /></a> 
            </div> 
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-5 red top-bar-items">
                   <div class="content">
                      <div class="row-fluid">
                           <div class="col-md-9 green col-sm-7 col-xm-6">            
                                <a href="#"><img src="images/linkedin.png" /></a>
                                <a href="#"><img src="images/linkedin.png" /></a>
                                <a href="#"><img src="images/linkedin.png" /></a>                            
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 blue col-sm-5 col-xm-6">            
                                <a href="#"><img src="images/default.png" /></a> 
                                <a href="#"><img src="images/default.png" /></a>                          
                            </div> 
                       </div>  
                   </div>  
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 text-center visible-desktop">                
                <div style="padding-top:20px;">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/header.png" /></a>                
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="col-md-6 blue"> 
            Something2
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 red">
               Something2
            </div>
        </div>
     </div> 
    </header>
    <script src="files/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="files/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The html code I am referring to is the following:

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-5 red top-bar-items">
                   <div class="content">
                      <div class="row-fluid">
                           <div class="col-md-9 green col-sm-7 col-xm-6">            
                                <a href="#"><img src="images/linkedin.png" /></a>
                                <a href="#"><img src="images/linkedin.png" /></a>
                                <a href="#"><img src="images/linkedin.png" /></a>                            
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 blue col-sm-5 col-xm-6">            
                                <a href="#"><img src="images/default.png" /></a> 
                                <a href="#"><img src="images/default.png" /></a>                          
                            </div> 
                       </div>  
                   </div>  
            </div>
```

This when on medium and large screens displays in a single row but when displayed on a small screen it breaks into two rows which is the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is the reason why we use responsive design.

Comment: What is col-xm-6? shouldn't that be col-xs-6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [AntB pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25014696/#comment38898014_25014696), this is just a case of accidentally using `col-xm-6` instead of `col-xs-6`.

When a column size is applied for any screen screen size, all sizes below it are automatically given a width of 12 columns unless otherwise specified. In this case the class `col-xm-6` doesn't hit any rules so it doesn't tell bootstrap anything.  When there are more than 12 columns worth of elements in a given `row`, they just wrap over into the next row, so your two small 12-column width divs just wrapped into two rows.

Change it to this:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-md-9 green col-sm-7 col-xs-6">
            <!-- content -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 blue col-sm-5 col-xs-6">
            <!-- content -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### [Demo in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/4n2Dr/)

Comment: Thank you! Can I also ask why the column size doesn't get the width of 100% since I specify that in the .row-fluid? When you see the page in a small screen now the 3 icons wrap into 2 rows because the two column DIVs do not stretch to fill the space available.

Comment: It's because `display: table-row` makes the div only take up as much space as it needs